# System or external system as an actor in a use case?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

Let's image a new simple CRM, where...

- some external system A uploads new data, CRM saves them
- CRM validates the data and creates eg. new cases from them
- user displays the cases

These requirements relate to systems and external systems, and I have some doubts about whether these qualify as actor or not:

1st possible use-case diagram:
[image: 1st uc diagram]

2nd possible use-case diagram:
[image: 2nd uc diagram]

My question about the borderline between system and actor can be decomposed as follows:

1. I believe, that the 1st diagram is wrong, because the system shouldn't be an actor. And it should look like the 2nd diagram. Correct?
2. The use cases "validate data" and "create new cases" will include in the scenario only steps made by the system (System validates number of columns;System validates data types;System validates mandatory values...).
   The system shouldn't be an "actor entity", however it's not against the rules to have a uc where the system is the only acting part, right? It's just important, that the uc has a relationship to some another uc which is really valuable for some actor. Correct?
3. Is it correct to show "external system A" as an actor? Executing the usecase should bring a value to the actor... I am not sure, whether system A makes happy to upload the data :) however systems may have a different point of view on what is a "value"

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about UC modelling as long as you are on the start position. You are about to go the wrong track.

Comment: I've slightly edited your question to make clear that it's one question (borderline btw system and actor) and that the 3 points are all details of this question.  Otherwise this could be understood as a question lacking focus and going in all directions. I hope it's ok. If not you can roll-back or edit further :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actors are always external to the system:

- The system under consideration can never be an actor.  When having the system as actor candidate, it often means that the corresponding use-case is not a use-case but some internal details.
- Other systems can be actors, if they are independent of the system under consideration and have some autonomy in this regard.

An immediate conclusion, is that the first diagram is incorrect, but the second might provide irrelevant details instead of true use cases.  More specifically:

1. Correct, as explained above
2. More or less correct: but a system feature that is of no use to anybody, and nobody cares, does not provide observable results valued by actors or stakeholders.  It hence does not qualify as use-case. Instead of "upload data" (what the system has to do), think of it in terms of objective for the users (what is the user's objective, e.g. "Obtain information about ...."
3. It depends. The key questions are: "is it independent and autonomous?" (if it's an upload script written to feed the system, it's not really independent), and "do the users care?"  (for example, because the external system offers a service that contributes to use-case adding some business value).

Comment: UC understanding is sort of a sad story....

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as for a book recommendation. I feel I tend to use the uc as a functional decomposition because we do it in my current project... May I follow up with another three questions? It really helps me..

Comment: 4) So the situation above should in a form of a use case simply look like "user > display new cases". With the scenario steps: 1. external system X sends the data 2. system uploads the data 3. system validates the data 4. system creates cases 5. user displays cases on screen blah blah. Keep it simple, right?

Comment: 5) If I want to provide more details about eg. "upload the data part" as an entry for a developer, it's correct to provide only text scenario (like in a use case) or eg. an activity diagram in EA?

Comment: 6) In a project where I participate our lead tends to create a use case for "everything" what a systems does. Thus our main EA directory is called "use cases", but I think we should split it to real "use cases" and something else ("system's actions" duno the name) for a mix of more detailed documentation of a system executed actions.

Comment: Follow up questions need to go into separate threads, not in the comments

Comment: @M_Ryan 4) indeed keep it simple. If the goal is to see the cases, that will be it. If the upload of the cases is of no additional value, don't show it: it's an internal detail how the new cases are prepared. But if you present it, show it with a wording from the point of view of the users.

Comment: 5) The remark is general for all use cases, whether on diagram or in textual form. Use case is NOT about internal activities of the system (by definition!).  But use cases internal behavioral details can be modelled with sequence diagrams or activity diagrams. Activities in particular are definitively a source of technical work.

Comment: If you can formulate the question in more general terms, the best is indeed to post a new question.